# How can I disable the virtual-terminal-switching shortcut keys in X?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, xorg, shortcut-keys, virtual-console

On earlier versions of Ubuntu, the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F☒</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>⇆</kbd> shortcut keys for switching between virtual terminals seem to have been disabled under X Windows, so it wasn't possible to trigger them accidentally.

I'm now using Ubuntu 16.04 with Cinnamon desktop environment, and the shortcuts are enabled even under X Windows.

I frequently trigger them accidentally while trying to access menu items or to go forwards/backwards in a web browser.

How can I disable these virtual terminal shortcut keys, or replace them with the versions that require <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>)?

--

(I've found several older answers that suggest a custom `xmodmap`, but this seems to have no effect for me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread at Unix stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146060/how-to-disable-alt-arrow-switching-of-virtual-consoles) helped me figure out a temporary one-off solution:

```
# This command removes all the lines that look like:
#    alt keycode 123 = Console_1'
# ... with no additional modifiers
$ sudo dumpkeys | grep -Pv '^\s+alt(gr)?\s+keycode\s+\d+\s+=\s+(Console_|Incr_Console|Decr_Console)'|sudo loadkeys
```

It seems that Ubuntu 16.04's console-setup package stores its cached keymap at `/etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz`.

But I can't figure out what program generates this "cache" in the first place. Any ideas? All I can tell is that re-running `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup console-setup-linux` triggers its regeneration.

Answer (score 3):

For a permanent fix, you can add your modified mapping to `/etc/console-setup/remap.inc`.

You must run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup -phigh` to apply the changes and reboot.

For example, this what I use to disable alt-Fxx and alt arrow switching

```
# Remap alt+Fxx key to void to avoid terminal switching
alt     keycode  59 = VoidSymbol
alt     keycode  60 = VoidSymbol
alt     keycode  61 = VoidSymbol
alt     keycode  62 = VoidSymbol
alt     keycode  63 = VoidSymbol
alt     keycode  64 = VoidSymbol
alt     keycode  65 = VoidSymbol
alt     keycode  66 = VoidSymbol
alt     keycode  67 = VoidSymbol
alt     keycode  68 = VoidSymbol
# Also remove mapping for alt left arrow and right arrow
alt keycode 105 = VoidSymbol
alt keycode 106 = VoidSymbol
```

`

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the command in terminal
`sudo kbd_mode -s`
and see if it helps. It changes keyboard input mode to "scancode". I had the same issue and found that this may be the solution.

Comment: Made my keyboard unusable on Ubuntu 19.04.